# Firefox issue new Date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, firefox

I'm having issues parsing data, I'm bring back a variable called.

starttime: which contains 2016-05-09 13:00:00

I'm then creating a new date called start and adding the starttime values to it. But start is coming back invalid ?

```
 var starttime = firstresponse.data.starttime;
 var start = new Date(starttime);
```

Comment: Don't parse strings using the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent). Always manually parse strings, a library can help but generally isn't needed. BTW, Safari returns an invalid date too.

Comment: Okay thanks for your advice will look into it more.